# Are there any good reasons to not have your application deal with any transactions?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring, transactions

Are there any good reasons why one would not have transaction management in their code?

The question came up when talking with a dba who gets very nervous when I bring up spring/hibernate.  I mention that Spring can handle transactions, in use with Hibernate mapping tables to objects etc, and the issue comes up that the database(Oracle10g) already handles transaction management, so we should just use that.  He even offered up the idea that we create a bunch of DB procedures to do inserts/updates so the database can handle things more efficiently, returning a 0/1 on whether the insert/update worked.

Are there any good reasons to not have your application deal with any transactions?  Is my dba clueless?  I'm thinking he is, but I'm not a great speaker when I'm unsure of the answer...  which is why I'm out looking for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding here.

The point is that database doesn't manage transactions in the same sense as Spring/Hibernate.

Database "manages transactions" by providing transactional behaviour, and your application "manages transactions" by using that behaviour and defining transaction boundaries (in particular, with the help of Spring or Hibernate).

Since boundaries of transactions are defined by business logic, implementing an application without transaction management would require you to move all your business logic to the database side. Even if you implement simple insert/update operations as stored procedures, it won't be enough to free application from transaction management as long as application needs to define that several inserts/updates should be executed inside the same transaction.

Comment: Worth adding that Oracle, unlike some other database products, doesn't require an explicit BEGIN TRANSACTION (unless you get into using a SERIALIZABLE isolation level which is a separate topic). But don't try criticizing the DBA unless you can clearly understand transactional concepts such as phantom reads and writes, dirty reads etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure if you mean that there will be a bunch of crud stored procedures (that do single inserts or updates), or if there will be stored procedures encompassing business logic (transaction scripts). If you mean the crud stored procedures, that is an entirely bad idea. (Actually even if you start with the crud approach you will end up with transaction scripts as business logic accretes, so it amounts to the same thing.) If you mean transaction scripts, that's an approach some places take. It is painful and there is no reuse, and you end up with a bunch of very complex stored procedures that are terribly hard to test. But DBAs like it because they know what's going on.

There is also an argument (applying to Transaction Scripts) that it's faster because there are less round trips, you have one call to the stored procedure that goes and does everything and returns a result, as opposed to your usual Spring/Hibernate application where you have multiple queries or updates and each statement is going over the network to the database (although Hibernate caches and reorders to try to minimize this). Minimizing network round-trips is probably the most valid reason for this approach, you have to weigh whether it is worth sacrificing flexibility for the reduced network traffic, or if it is a premature optimization.

Another argument made in favor of transaction scripts is that less competence is required to implement the system correctly. In particular Hibernate expertise is not required. You can hire a horde of code monkeys and have them bang out the code. All the hard stuff is removed from them and placed under the DBA's control.

So, to recap, here are the arguments for transaction scripts:

- Less network traffic
- Cheap developers
- total DBA control (from your point of view, he will be a total bottleneck)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, there's no way to "use transactions" from the database standpoint without making your application aware of it at *some* level. Although, if you're using Spring, you can make this fairly painless by using `<tx:annotation-driven>` and applying the `@Transactional` annotations to the relevant methods in the service implementation classes.

That said, there are times when you should bypass transactions and write directly to the database. Specifically any time when speed is more important than guaranteed data integrity.